# How to marshal a Byte Array with reference to a C Program?

Tags: c, vb.net, marshalling

I have a C-Function DecodePacket(BYTE* packet, int size) and i want to use it through dll import in Vb.net. Is it Possible that i give this parameter like a byref, so that the c-function uses the same packet as i put in. If this is not possible, how can i return a byte Array from C to Vb.net

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily use ByRef, that would make it a BYTE**.  This must be declared as `<In,Out> ByVal packet As Byte()`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in such situations I use the IntPtr structure for marshalling. Byte* packet it is indeed a pointer to the first item of the byte array. Using the pointer and having the size should be enough to get the data.